# How to underline text in MFC C++

Tags: c++, mfc, text-editor

I am new to C++ so forgive me if this question is too general.....
I am using VS2010 to create a simple MFC text editor in C++. At the moment I am trying to get the following basic functionality up and running: a toolbar that has an underline button that underlines the selected text when you click it.

I have scoured the internet for a solution but have only come up with the following:

http://aclacl.brinkster.net/MFC/ch12e.htm

however either this code is incomplete or I can't figure out how they link the actual button to the command handlers(or whatever they call the code that executes the actual underlining).

Can someone kindly:

a) clarify where the underline button is found in StyleBar.cpp

OR

b) point me in the direction of a better solution if one exists.

Much Thanks.

Comment: It looks like underlining is handled in MyWordView in that code sample, not StyleBar.

Comment: The underline button is attached to ID ID_CHAR_UNDERLINE, which is probably in the resource file somewhere, and handled in the CView derived class CMyWordView.
The above example looks to be a good start for what you are looking for. good luck

Comment: It says in the article under the section on "The Style Bar" that "Clicking the Bold button, for example, activates *CMyWordView::OnCharBold*".  A quick glance at the code for `CMyWordView` reveals a very similar method called `OnCharUnderline()`.

Comment: user1158692 - I do in fact remember thinking about that when i read it in the article....but what I can't wrap my head around is exactly how clicking the bold button activates CMyWordView::OnCharBold.....where exactly in the code is the link between the button and the method? For example, wouldn't there be some sort of event listening method that links underline_button to CMyWordView::OnCharUnderline? For that matter where is the underline button actually defined??

Comment: Max - So are you saying that in order to establish a link between the GUI button 'Underline' to the command handler CMyWordView::OnCharUnderline you just need to:

Comment: Max - I've looked into what you said.....So are you saying that in order to establish a link between the GUI button 'Underline' to the command handler CMyWordView::OnCharUnderline you just need to: 1) in the resource file define the variable ID_CHAR_UNDERLINE 2) also in the resource file link the MENUITEM to ID_CHAR_UNDERLINE 3) then make the link between ID and CMyWordView::OnCharUnderline using ON_COMMAND?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP`...`END_MESSAGE_MAP` block is where the message queue mapping to handlers happens.  Specifically the line `ON_COMMAND(ID_CHAR_UNDERLINE, OnCharUnderline)` maps the `WM_COMMAND` for the underline control identifier to the method `OnCharUnderline` which handles setting the selection style.  The page you reference doesn't include the resource file(s).  The toolbar itself appears to be constructed on the previous page of the article.

Comment: A Windows command message.  It's what's happening on your application's message queue underneath the MFC covers.

Comment: When you click one of the buttons, the WM_COMMAND with the button's identifier is put on to the message queue.  The messages are popped off the queue and handled by the application.   MFC hides the queue from the application developer and provides macros (the MESSAGE_MAP) for binding the message to class methods.

Comment: And if I'm understanding you correctly.....the WM_COMMAND you are referring to is ON_COMMAND(ID_CHAR_UNDERLINE, OnCharUnderline)?

Comment: That's correct.  In fact if you look at how the ON_COMMAND macro is defined, you will see it referenced there (as well as some other hidden complexities).

Comment: Nitpick: The messages are mapped to *instance* methods, not *class* methods.